# Clutch Pedal Problem

Tags: land-rover, freelander, clutch-pedal

In the process of driving home yesterday evening my clutch pedal suddenly changed from its normal position to much higher. I still managed to put my foot on it to depress and change gear and this without undue force except to have to lift my foot much higher and didn't have to use any more force than usual to press it to floor in order to change gear.  Gear changed without problem, force or noise.
What could this be ?  Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/make/model/engine of the vehicle in question?

Comment: Land Rover Freelander 2009 2.0 Diesel 24 years old. One Owner, careful driver, regularly serviced.

Comment: Wouldn't a 2009 make it 14-ish years old?